# How to coordinate two linux processes to run in a two step lockstep schedule?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am testing some reliability scenarios and I would like how write a script or a small application to realize a running schedule for 2 alternating (live/dead) processes like:

```
First 30s: ProcessA - start, run 
Next  30s: ProcessB - start, run
Next  30s: ProcessA - kill -9, Process B run
Next  30s, ProcessB - kill -9, Process A start, run
Next  30s, ProcessB - start, run, Process A, run
```

Etc.

With the condition that the schedule never has processes killed (or has the intervals in which both are killed overlap). **We can ignore failures** and assume for the purpose of this script the machine/machines it will run on will not fail and the processes will not fail outside the simulated kill -9 in the script.

So I need some sort of barrier-based coordination... but don't know how to realize it in bash.

This is what I am trying to do, but needless to say it does not work. Upon running the script instantiates $PROGRAM1, $PROGRAM2, and $PROGRAM3 (examples are just for intuition) and then gets stuck forever. **It does not alternate** kill -9 and restarting them in this 2-step lockstep. In other words **the loop does not loop.**

```
  PROGRAM1 = "echo P1; sleep 100"
  PROGRAM2 = "echo P2; sleep 100"
  PROGRAM3 = "echo P3; sleep 600"

  $PROGRAM1 &
  echo Started $PROGRAM1
  PID1=$!
  $PROGRAM2 &
  echo Started $PROGRAM2
  PID2=$!
  $PROGRAM3 &
  echo Started $PROGRAM3

  while 1; do
      sleep 10
      echo Killing $PROGRAM1
      kill -9 $PID1
      wait $PID1
      sleep 10
      echo Starting $PROGRAM1
      $PROGRAM1 &
      PID1=$!
      sleep 10
      echo Killing $PROGRAM2
      kill -9 $PID2
      wait $PID2
      sleep 10
      echo Starting $PROGRAM2
      $PROGRAM2 &
      PID2=$!
  done
```

$PROGRAM3 is one that monitors the two.

Comment: What is the point of such an arrangement please? Also, do the processes use common resources such as network ports?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a synchronization scheme where these processes synchronize state on startup. I want to see how quick and reliably they can do that. Having both processes not run at the same time would lose the state so I want a guarantee that cannot happen. They connect to eachother, there's a static configuration file for each that contains what port each is listening to so they can establish a connection.

Comment: So, if we call the time when both processes are running the *"overlap time"*, and the time when just one process is running the *"single time"*, you want to keep alternating between the two processes whilst reducing the overlap time till it becomes unreliable, correct?

Comment: I would set the "overlap time" and the "single time" manually. I am not seeking to modify these dynamically during the test. Each process accumulates data. Ultimately, I want to see how fast one recovers with no data loss by reducing the overlap time. Other test cases exist as well but in principle I am looking to be able to get a lower bound for performance reasons.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Thanks for you comment @jww. Not sure what does not make it a particular programming problem. The problem is that I need to start, let run, and shut down these processes in the particular sequence I have presented, using a bash script, and the bottom line question is how to solve this problem as such. Would you mind telling me why this is not particular enough.

Comment: There is no way to guarantee 100% coverage, all you can do is build redundancy to inorease the number of nines. If your needs are demanding, maybe look into real-time kernel stuff. But I'm guessing your question is really how to *approximate* 100% well enough with a stock kernel, where obviously "enough" depends on your requirements, but this is not yet specified at all in your question.

Comment: This is a simple script to test process synchronization. The guarantees I need are schedule-based with respect to the sequence of run/kill for each process that it generates. We can assume no failures outside what is simulated by the script: no machine failures, and no other  process failures.

Comment: *"Needless to say it doesn't work"* - why? What does it do wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you need a barrier? And where?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's a thought. From some of the research I made barriers are used to create _phases_ of execution and synchronize processes with respect to them. Unfortunately I'm not experienced with barriers, with bash, or with barriers in bash, if such a construct exists in the language (I think it's wait... but there could be details that do not make it true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work fine...

---

`program1`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo PROGRAM1
sleep 100
```

---

`program2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo PROGRAM2
sleep 100
```

---

`master`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./program1 &
echo Started program1
PID1=$!
./program2 &
echo Started program2
PID2=$!

while : ; do
      sleep 10
      echo Killing program1
      kill -9 $PID1
      wait $PID1
      sleep 10
      echo Starting program1
      ./program1 &
      PID1=$!
      sleep 10
      echo Killing program2
      kill -9 $PID2
      wait $PID2
      sleep 10
      echo Starting program2
      ./program2 &
      PID2=$!
  done
```

---

**Sample Output**

```
Started program1
Started program2
PROGRAM1
PROGRAM2
Killing program1
./master: line 13: 90499 Killed: 9               ./program1
Starting program1
PROGRAM1
Killing program2
./master: line 21: 90500 Killed: 9               ./program2
Starting program2
PROGRAM2
Killing program1
./master: line 13: 90505 Killed: 9               ./program1
Starting program1
PROGRAM1
Killing program2
./master: line 21: 90512 Killed: 9               ./program2
Starting program2
PROGRAM2
```

It works just the same without the `wait` commands too. And it goes around the loop. I am baffled as to what the problem is.